# Error 1004 Delete method of Range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

When I start a new secession, I want to delete old data between specific sheets. (Between Green & Red) . Unfortunately I get this error message and can’t figure out what I do wrong.

“Error 1004 Delete method of Range class failed “

Please Help !
Thanks.

```
'-----------------------------
Sub Test()
'-----------------------------
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim beginIdx As Integer, endIdx As Integer

    '-- Get the 'Green' and 'Red' indexses in the active workbook .
    beginIdx = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Green").Index + 1
    endIdx = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Red").Index - 1

    '-- Delete old data between 'Green' and 'Red' tabs
    For J = beginIdx To endIdx

        '-- Set this to the relevant worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(J)

        With ws
              '-- Get the last row and last column
              lRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
              lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

              '-- Set the  sheet range to delete old data leaving the headings intact
              Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

              Application.DisplayAlerts = False   ' Get rid of pop-up message

              With Rng
                    '-- Now delete the old data from the sheet
                    .EntireRow.Delete
              End With

              Application.DisplayAlerts = True    ' Back to normal
        End With

    Next J

End Sub
```

Comment: what values in your `lRow` and `lCol` when debugging?

Comment: lRow = 2 and lCol = 38

Comment: it works for me..can you show your workbook (e.g. using https://www.dropbox.com)?

Comment: It works for me too now . I jst have to do a If statement in my code to check the lRow value. Thanks to YOU ..

Answer (score 1):

This Works now. I just have to include: 
* If statement to check the lRow value is > 2 
* Increase the Range cell value from 2 -> 3 ( Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3,1)...)

```
'-----------------------------
Sub Test()
'-----------------------------
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim beginIdx As Integer, endIdx As Integer

    '-- Get the 'Green' and 'Red' indexses in the active workbook .
    beginIdx = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Green").Index + 1
    endIdx = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Red").Index - 1

    '-- Delete old data between 'Green' and 'Red' tabs
    For J = beginIdx To endIdx

        '-- Set this to the relevant worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(J)

        With ws
              '-- Get the last row and last column
              lRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
              lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

              '-- Set the  sheet range to delete old data leaving the headings intact
              If lRow > 2 Then
                   Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

                   Application.DisplayAlerts = False   ' Get rid of pop-up message

                  With Rng
                        '-- Now delete the old data from the sheet
                        .EntireRow.Delete
                  End With
             End If 

              Application.DisplayAlerts = True    ' Back to normal
        End With

    Next J

End Sub
```